# How to handle exception System.ArgumentException

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, try-catch

I use this code in my application to manage a folder:

```
Dim appBasePath As String = Application.StartupPath() 
Dim appPath As String = appBasePath & "\user"   
Private WithEvents FSW As New IO.FileSystemWatcher(appPath)
```

But if the path does not exist the application is throwing this exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.dll

Additional information: The directory name c:\program\user is invalid.
```

And this:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The directory name c:\program\user is invalid.
```

How can i handle this exception?

Comment: Depends, you probably shouldn't.  Just validate the data you use, if Directory.Exists(appPath) returns *false* then nothing good is going to happen next.  Tell the user about it.

Comment: The problem is that the application crashes if the path is not found... How can i show this message to user: `MsgBox("Path not found.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")` and close the application? Maybe in Form Load event.. i dont know.. i am very new to this.... How can i validade the data in this statement? `Private WithEvents FSW As New IO.FileSystemWatcher(appPath)`

Comment: You cannot get good advice when you don't tell us where *appPath* comes from.  How does its value get set?  Show more code.

Comment: @Hans Passant The `appPath` comes from here: `Dim appBasePath As String = Application.StartupPath() 
Dim appPath As String = appBasePath & "\user"`

Comment: Post the **real** exception message.

Comment: Have you considered that that might not be a good directory to be watching? Programs are usually installed somewhere under "C:\Program Files" or "C:\Program Files (x86)" (or their equivalent in different languages), to which a normal user does not have write access. Perhaps you could have a configuration section to set which entity should be watched.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle the exception is by instantiate the object inside a method block in which then you can write the try/catch block.

An example:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1 : Inherits Form

    Dim appBasePath As String = Application.StartupPath()
    Dim appPath As String = appBasePath & "\user"

    Friend WithEvents Fsw As FileSystemWatcher

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        MyClass.InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Try
            Me.Fsw = New FileSystemWatcher(appPath)

        Catch ex As ArgumentException When (Not Directory.Exists(appPath))
        ' ...

        Catch ex As Exception
        ' ...

        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```